# Need to create azure failover group using AzureCLI

Tags: azure-cli

How to create azure failover group for managed instances by using AzureCLI

I need the above question answer

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and successfully created failover groups through azure cli**

**Command:**

```
az sql failover-group create --name group234 --resource-group <resource group name > --server <server name> --partner-server <partner server name> --subscription < subscription id >
```

**Console:**

I executed the above command, and it created **`failover-group`** successfully.

[image]

**Portal:**

After I executed above commands, I can see the groups through portal.

[image]

**Reference:**
[az sql failover-group | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/failover-group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-failover-group-create)